Is there any way to remux vob to mp4 from the context menu, using FFmpeg?
I'm aware FFmpeg has commands to be able to do this, but I don't want to type them every time.
Is there a way to add an option, like “Remux to MP4”, to the context menu, so I can simply right click on it, have FFmpeg remux all the VOBs to MP4 in the same source folder without typing the commands manually?

You have two separate problems here: You need a script or command to remux to mp4, and then you need to modify your context menu. What have you tried so far to accomplish these two things? What research have you done?

I got a partial solution with AI, it gave me this reg key, which I adjusted to the location of ffmpeg, problem is , it does not name the remuxed file to the filename of the original. Also I'm trying to find a way to allow for batch processing where I can process a bunch of vobs at once.

Reg key: Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations.vob\shell\Remux\command]
@="cmd.exe /k ffmpeg -i "%1" -c:v copy -c:a aac "%~dpn1.mp4" && ren "%~dpn1.mp4" "%~n1.mp4""

Please include that information in the question itself. Please also note that this is not a script writing service. AI is only marginally helpful, and it requires that you know a lot about what you're doing to manipulate or correct or complete whatever it gives you.
